# Storing indices of rows and columns already added to clusters

Tags: python, numpy

My question is about hierarchical clustering. I'm trying to create a hierarchical clustering algorithm from scratch in Python from a given distance matrix. I want to get the same output as the linkage function from scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage. But I'm running into an issue when I want to add an indice of a file (row/column in the distance matrix) to a cluster that was formed earlier in the algorithm.

```
def cluster(distance_matrix):

    n = len(distance_matrix)

    cluster_dictionary = {i:i for i in range(n)}
    linkage_matrix = np.zeros((n - 1, 4))

    for i in range(n - 1):
        # Create a mask with True on all values that are not on the diagonal
        mask = np.ones(distance_matrix.shape, dtype=bool)
        np.fill_diagonal(mask, 0)

        # Find the index of the minimum distance between two texts disregarding the diagonal
        min_distance = np.min(distance_matrix[mask])
        ind = np.where(distance_matrix == min_distance)[0]

        # Gather the indices of our clusters from the indices of our distance matrix
        cluster_ind = [cluster_dictionary[idx] for idx in ind]

        # Update our cluster_dictionary so each index is properly assigned to a cluster
        for text_idx in cluster_ind:
            if text_idx > n - 1:
                for k, v in cluster_dictionary.items():
                    if v == text_idx:
                        cluster_dictionary[k] = i + n
            else:
                cluster_dictionary[text_idx] = i + n

        linkage_matrix[i, 0] = cluster_ind[0]
        linkage_matrix[i, 1] = cluster_ind[1]
        linkage_matrix[i, 2] = min_distance
        linkage_matrix[i, 3] = 0

        # Calculate the new distances our texts are from our newly found cluster
        distance_vector = distance_from_cluster(ind, distance_matrix)

        # Remove the row and column that we just clustered, also remove it from our custom indices
        distance_matrix = delete_row_column(distance_matrix, ind)

        # Insert our new distance vector for the clustered group into the distance matrix
        distance_matrix = np.insert(distance_matrix, 0, distance_vector[1:], axis=0) 
        distance_matrix = np.insert(distance_matrix, 0, distance_vector, axis=1) 

    return np.array(linkage_matrix)
```

When I run:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd

distance_matrix = np.array([[0, 9, 3, 6, 11],
                            [9, 0, 7, 5, 10],
                            [3, 7, 0, 9, 2],
                            [6, 5, 9, 0, 8],
                            [11, 10, 2, 8, 0]])


own_linkage = cluster(distance_matrix)
print(own_linkage)
print()
print(hierarchy.linkage(ssd.squareform(distance_matrix), method='complete', metric='cosine'))
```

I get:

```
[[ 2.  4.  2.  0.]
 [ 5.  3.  5.  0.]
 [ 0.  6.  9.  0.]
 [ 7.  1. 11.  0.]]

[[ 2.  4.  2.  2.]
 [ 1.  3.  5.  2.]
 [ 0.  6.  9.  3.]
 [ 5.  7. 11.  5.]]
```

Disregarding the last column, my algorithm makes a mistake in the second row of the linkage matrix.

I think it has to do with the fact that because I when add any newly found clusters in my function to my distance matrix, I change the indices a bit which makes my `cluster_dictionary` wrong. I figured that storing a custom index of sorts might solve this issue, but I can't find a good programmatic way to solve this. I think it might also go wrong in calculating the distance from a newly added cluster to another file in the distance matrix, but this issue might stem from the issue mentioned before.

Here are the functions I use in the program above:

```
def delete_row_column(distance_matrix, indices):
    """Returns the distance matrix with the rows and columns specified in indices
    deleted"""
    remain_ind = [i for i in range(len(distance_matrix)) if not i in indices]
    distance_matrix = distance_matrix[np.ix_(remain_ind, remain_ind)]
    return distance_matrix


def distance_from_cluster(cluster, distance_matrix):
    """Finds all distances that our texts are from the cluster defined as the longest distance
    from a point within our cluster to a given text"""
    distance_vector = [0]
    for i, distance_row in enumerate(distance_matrix):
        distances = [distance_row[i] for i in cluster]
        # Disregard texts already in the cluster
        if not 0 in distances:
            distance_vector.append(np.max(distances))
    return np.array(distance_vector)
```